# Android Studio Preview Panel displays LOADING

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Preview Panel always displays 'LOADING'. What would be the possible solution.
[LOADING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoUGK.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try rebuild your project [image]

or you can try invalidate caches

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your kind support. But I tried both of the above options but it still displays the LOADING in the preview panel

Comment: maybe you can try syncron gradle

Comment: Ok I will try once again Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshoot for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IP5k.png)It's gradle Problem, gradle was not properly synced or gradle was not found and your activity_main.xml file contain many errors.